# Mysql join on null

Tags: mysql, join, null

I have 2 tables, each with 3 columns to join with.

```
table A
c1 c2   c3
10 NULL NULL
10 NULL 1
10 1    NULL

table B
c1 c2   c3
10 NULL NULL
10 NULL 1
10 1    NULL
```

I would like to join them so that NULL = NULL, so

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.c1 = b.c1 AND a.c2 = b.c2 AND a.c3 = b.c3
```

I would like it to join on NULL should match NULL. So that in the end I'm getting the 3 records:

```
table A+B
c1 c2   c3   c1 c2   c3
10 NULL NULL 10 NULL NULL
10 NULL 1    10 NULL 1
10 1    NULL 10 1    NULL
```

is this possible somehow? I have tried also with IFNULL but did'n get the results what I expect. I would be grateful if you could point me to the right direction. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `NULL`-safe equality operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM a JOIN
     b
     ON a.c1 <=> b.c1 AND a.c2 <=> b.c2 AND a.c3 <=> b.c3;
```

However, with your sample data, a `join` on the first column is sufficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM a JOIN
     b
     ON a.c1 = b.c1 ;
```

Comment: crazy, I don't know, I've tried that also, it didn't work. Now works. I have a feeling that maybe sqlyog is buggy a little bit or something. By the way I've updated the question so that it's not sufficient to join only on c1. Many thanks!

Comment: Gordon Linoff...! always the first to answer sql questions, thanks for providing good answers where we are learning from you new and good things.